# Regex to find specific strings outside complicated brackets

Tags: java, regex

If I wanted to get the words TEST,BEST,FEST if found outside curly brackets I would use the following regex:

```
^(?:[^\{]*(?:\{.*\})*)(?:(?:[^\{]*(TEST|BEST|FEST))|(?:.*(TEST|BEST|FEST)(?!\})))
```

see https://regex101.com/r/vB2fS0/1

but what if I would like to get these words if found outside complicated brackets for example outside {[ something }. notice the **{[** instead of just **{**.
examples:

1. {[TEST} - is valid hence no match
2. {[} {[BEST} - is valid hence no match
3. bla {[} {[FEST} - is valid hence no match
4. TEST - is invalid since its outside complicated brackets  hence **should** match
5. {[} {[FEST - is invalid hence **should** match
6. bla {[} hi {[} TEST} {[} - is invalid hence **should** match

The issue is that with 1 character **{** I can easily use `[^\{]*` to exclude it. how can I do it with multiple characters i.e. a word: **{[**

Comment: Match and capture what you need, and just match what you do not need. Grab the Group 1 value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a capturing group for the values you need and just match all others. In other words, match and capture what you need, and just match what you do not need. Grab the Group 1 value.

```
\{\[[^}]*}|(TEST|BEST|FEST)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mH5sK9/1)

The `\{\[[^}]*}` matches `{[`, any 0+ characters other than `}` up to the first `}` and these values you do not need. The values you need are in Group 1.

Sample code:

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("{[TEST}", "{[} {[BEST}", "bla {[} {[FEST}", "TEST","{[} {[FEST", "bla {[} hi {[} TEST} {[}");
for (String str : strs)
{
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\{\\[[^}]*}|(TEST|BEST|FEST)").matcher(str);
    while(m.find()) {
        if (m.group(1) != null) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1) + " found in '" + str + "'");
        }
    }
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/wx6DFN)

**If you need to replace those values**, use a `Matcher#appendReplacement`:

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("{[TEST}", "{[} {[BEST}", "bla {[} {[FEST}", "TEST","{[} {[FEST", "bla {[} hi {[} TEST} {[}");
for (String str : strs)
{
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\{\\[[^}]*}|(TEST|BEST|FEST)").matcher(str);
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    while(m.find()) {
        if (m.group(1) != null) {
            m.appendReplacement(result, "NEW_"+m.group(1));
        } else {
            m.appendReplacement(result, m.group(0));
        }
    }
    m.appendTail(result);
    System.out.println(result.toString());
}
```

See [another Java demo](http://ideone.com/cZSE8p)

Comment: Note that `(TEST|BEST|FEST)` can be matches with a mere `([TBF]EST)`, so use this if you need to match those literals.

Comment: thanks a lot. what about {[%%TEST%% {[%%TEST%%} ? can we match on this one too? the first TEST is outside the brackets. can we match if a new brackets start before current one is closed? for example https://regex101.com/r/gG9fR8/1

Comment: Yes, you may use a tempered greedy token then: [`\{\[(?:(?!}|\{\[).)*}|(TEST|BEST|FEST)`](https://regex101.com/r/gG9fR8/3), or an unrolled version of that one: [`\{\[[^{}]*(?:\{(?!\[)[^{}]*)*}|(TEST|BEST|FEST)`](https://regex101.com/r/gG9fR8/4) (it should be faster with longer strings).